# How shall I write unit test code in database driven app?

Tags: java, database, unit-testing, spring-mvc

I have database driven financial application. Most of my method and service depend on database to process. So I am using spring Integration test.Now I want to write also unit test for my app. As we know unit test depends on single component, how should I write unit test for my application where I know Unit testable code is better designed and less error prone. If I use mock or stub.. that won't be my real scenario. So my confusion, is unit test is not worthy for database driven app??

Answer (score 0):

You certainly can (and should) unit test a "database driven" app. Your goal when writing such tests is to verify the logic of the code you're testing, *not* the database layer. How you handle such code (e.g. with mocks, stubs, fakes, test databases, etc.) depends on exactly what you're testing.

Generally speaking you should structure your code so that it isn't tightly coupled to the database. A handful of classes, tops, are responsible for interacting with the database, while the rest are simply working with Java objects. Then when you test those classes you simply pass in test objects, no database required. For the handful of classes that need to directly interact with the database you can create mocks or use a fake database.